# Efficient way to populate matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Given a table comprising three columns,

```
1 2 0.05
1 3 0.04
2 3 0.001
```

and a matrix with defined dimensions,

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Is there an efficient way to populate the matrix with the entries in the third column of the table with R, without having to iterate over the table, isolate the indices and insert value in a for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the final product supposed to look like? Have you already tried something that doesn't work or takes too long? Where does your "table" above come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally tables are handled as matrices or arrays and matrix indexing allows two column arguments as (i,j)-indexing (and if the object being indexed has higher dimensions then matrices with more columns are used) so:

```
> inp.mtx <- as.matrix(inp)
> mat[inp.mtx[,1:2] ]<- inp.mtx[,3]
> mat
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   NA 0.05 0.040
[2,]   NA   NA 0.001
[3,]   NA   NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mat <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0.05, 0.04, 0.001), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
 mat

 mat1 <- matrix(c(rep(NA,6), 0.05, 0.04, 0.001), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
 mat1

 mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
 mat2
 mat2[,3] <- c(0.05, 0.04, 0.001)
 mat2



 df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 2), y=c(2, 3, 3), z=c(0.05, 0.04, 0.001))
 df

 mat3 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol =3)
 mat3
 mat3[,3] <- df$z
 mat3

 mat4 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol =3)
 mat4
 mat4[,3] <- unlist(df[3])
 mat4
```